# Incorrect frame range rendered in video edit

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.  For years, I have been able to do simple video editing, cuts, etc. and the range of frames was always rendered properly for audio and video.

Now, every video I create has the correct frame's worth of audio, but the video is not even close to being the right frames. As in 10 minutes before the frame selection. I don't remember changing anything. I've tried starting from scratch instead of using my saved defaults, nothing works. On some occasions, deleting the video from the workspace and importing a different video still renders parts of the previous video!

Has something changed with version 3.0.1?  The only thing I haven't done is uninstall and purge it.

Depending on the video (30 minute mp4) the preview is dead slow and messes up the render further.  Am I missing codecs or something?  The files play fine in vlc.

Comment: Hardware:  AMD Ryzen 3950-x 16 cores/32 thread, 64 GB ram.  No pro drivers, so GPU is not involved.

Comment: The plot thickens.  I tested bumping the frame rate to 60FPS and everything is fine now.  I thought Blender was supposed to auto detect the frame rate from the file?

Comment: Source files with VFR wasn't displayed correct. This should be solved from 3.3.